# azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection Unsupported attribute vpn_site_link_id

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, hashicorp

we are attempting to create an azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection using the documentation for it here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/vpn_gateway_connection#bgp_enabled
we are using

```
resource "azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection" "example" {
  name               = "example"
  vpn_gateway_id     = azurerm_vpn_gateway.example.id
  remote_vpn_site_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.id

  vpn_link {
    name             = "link1"
    vpn_site_link_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.vpn_site_link[0].id 
  }

  vpn_link {
    name             = "link2"
    vpn_site_link_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.vpn_site_link[1].id 
  }
}
```

we are getting errors when running terraform plan

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 95, in resource "azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection" "example":
│   95:     vpn_site_link_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.vpn_site_link[0].id
│
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "vpn_site_link".
╵
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [azurerm_vpn_site](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/vpn_site) does not have attribute `vpn_site_link`. I guess that maybe you wanted:

```
vpn_site_link_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.link[0].id
```

Similarly for the second case.

Comment: that change yields 
Error: Unexpected resource instance key
│ Because azurerm_vpn_site.example does not have "count" or "for_each" set, references to it must not include an index key. Remove the bracketed index to refer to the single instance of this resource.

Comment: @eiu165 You haven't provided definition of `azurerm_vpn_site.example` so I don't know how it is created. But I updated the answer based on the error.

Comment: I used the whole example from here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/vpn_gateway_connection, I just didn't paste the whole thing in the question

Comment: @eiu165 The example in the docs is incorrect sadly, thus you get your errors.

Comment: is it possible to add the vpn_link to the azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection?

Comment: @eiu165 I would suggest you to write code for that, and then either make new question with the real code of yours. Other wise its difficult to speculate what you are doing, what's in the docs, or what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did not change the example, I am just deploying the example as written here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/vpn_gateway_connection

Comment: when you say 'write code for that' do you mean I should inline some azure cli commands?

Comment: @eiu165  The only other possibility you can try now is with `vpn_site_link_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.link[0].id`. And by write the code, I mean provide full, reproducable example of your code, so that any one can copy and paste it to try to recreate your issue.

Comment: I edited the question to include all of my code   @Marcin

Comment: @eiu165 Did you try with `vpn_site_link_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.link[0].id`?

Comment: vpn_site_link_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.link[1].id
 worked  
 Thank you

Comment: can you update your answer , and I will accept it ?  thanks